# Cell validation from a CSV list stored in a cell

Tags: excel, list, validation, conditional-statements

I've been searching on Stack Overflow and generally googling around, but I keep getting tutorials on using multi-cell ranges for my validation source ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919908/dynamically-changing-dropdown-in-excel)).

I have a table of possible materials and associated qualities: density, protective value, cost per unit weight, availability, etc. Critically, one of the columns is "valid construction methods", and this cell contains a comma-separated-list of strings. The user picks one of these materials using a cell with a Validation drop-down (this part works fine).

I need a second drop-down that will show the valid construction methods that can be used with the material chosen from the first drop down. I could show ALL the construction methods by using the name column from my construction methods table as the validation restriction, but I only want the valid ones.

So, for example, if the user picks "Iron, hand forged" they shouldn't have the option to pick "Quilting" or "Layering on the bias" - those options are only valid for flexible fabric-like materials. And conversely, if they pick "Linen", they shouldn't have the ability to pick "Articulated Plate" - that's a nonsense value for Linen and other fabrics.

I can hand-type a comma-separated-list into the validation box and the drop-down list is produced correctly, but I can't give the validation box a VLOOKUP to a single cell containing a comma-separated-list (=VLOOKUP(Material, MaterialTbl,7,False)), it complains that the source must be a deliminated list or a reference to a single row or column.

I also tried putting the VLOOKUP in a cell and just pointing the validation box to that (=$H$16) but all I got was one option containing the entire list, commas and all. EG my list consisted of one option: "Mail, Segmented Plate, Scale, Plate" rather than four options: "Mail", "Segmented Plate", "Scale", "Plate".

Is there any way to do this?

Is there a way to do this without resorting to VBA? (I will resort to VBA if necessary, but I was hoping for a spreadsheet with no macros as it is easier to distribute).

Comment: Data validation does not allow arrays AFAIK.  You're probably best served re-organizing your spreadsheet to allow for dynamic named ranges (just add another sheet, or a hidden table somewhere that defines the valid construction methods for each Material, arranged in rows/columns.  Then you can create some dynamic named ranges to reference this table and return the appropriate list when the Material selection changes. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287

Comment: If I'm following the article (and the tutorials) correctly, this would require having a named range for each material type - that's going to make adding new materials to the table a bit challenging.

Comment: Woops - I just found [this tutorial](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/05/a-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) which looks like it gets around the problem of needing a static named range for each material type quite nicely.

Comment: Now if only I can figure out how to have one table build itself based on _transposed_ data from another table...

Comment: Gah, I can't use multi-cell formulas in a table, and I can't use a formula at all in a table header. :/

Comment: well at this point I don't know what you need. I am certain yours is more of a problem of spreadsheet design, than it is a limitation of Excel's functionality. One table, with a column for each Material type, and ONE dynamic ranged keyed off the Materials dropdown list should do the trick. I will post an example of this as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I still think you will be best off by creating a table and a defined dynamic range that keys off this table.

You can put this on a hidden worksheet, if necessary.

I would define two Named Ranges in the worksheet. `TableRange` will refer to the entire table, and `ListRange` will be a separate 1-column range that is dynamic based on selections in your dropdown menu.

Using some formula (can get complex) and dynamic ranges, it's pretty easy to make your drop-down lists "related" to one another.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYMUpQRmluVzRkcnM/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet1 explains how I set up the Named Ranges

Sheet2 has example dropdown menus, the top-level is linked to Cells `$A$1:$C$1` on Sheet1, and the second dropdown is linked to the dynamic `ListRange`.